# requests module not working in pycharm (only)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pycharm, python-idle

I was trying to create a web scraping program , which uses bs4 and requests library. What i noticed that whenever pycharm encounters `import requests` it just gets stuck and throws an error when i press **return** .The error is :

```
>>> import requests

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HP\64bit\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\HP\64bit\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\HP\64bit\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\logging\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from string import Template
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\Automate\string.py", line 28, in <module>
    t = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>>
```

Trying to do the same in IDLE shell or cmd window works just fine
I'm using windows 10 64-bit , python 64-bit 3.6.2rc1 & Pycharm 2017.1.4 community edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PYTHONPATH is screwed up, which is probably due to PyCharm's option to add the project root to PYTHONPATH (the option is in the "run" settings).

Due to the messed-up PYTHONPATH, the `string` import inside requests imports your `string.py` instead of the same module from the stdlib (the traceback clearly shows this by the way).

---

Easiest solution? Don't have top-level .py files, put them inside a package. That way only your package will be importable as a top-level package in PYTHONPATH but you don't end up having tons of new top-level modules.